# C# - Get Text Height from PDF Single Character

Tags: c#, pdf, itext

i need the text height from the charactor extracted from a pdf.
i have the following, just dont know how to get the text height.

```
static class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        PdfReader reader = new PdfReader("C:\\temp\\TestDrawing.pdf");
        var s = PdfTextExtractor.GetTextFromPage(reader, 1, new LocationTextExtractionStrategy(new my()));
    }
}

public class my : LocationTextExtractionStrategy.ITextChunkLocationStrategy
{

    public LocationTextExtractionStrategy.ITextChunkLocation CreateLocation(TextRenderInfo renderInfo, LineSegment baseline)
    {

        foreach (TextRenderInfo tr in renderInfo.GetCharacterRenderInfos())
        {
            LineSegment bl = tr.GetBaseline();
            string text = tr.GetText(); //gets text charactor 
            float startpointX = bl.GetStartPoint()[Vector.I1]; 
            float startpointY = bl.GetStartPoint()[Vector.I2];
            float endpointX = bl.GetEndPoint()[Vector.I1];
            float endpointY = bl.GetEndPoint()[Vector.I2];
            //now need to get the height of the text
        }
        return new LocationTextExtractionStrategy.TextChunkLocationDefaultImp(baseline.GetStartPoint(), baseline.GetEndPoint(), renderInfo.GetSingleSpaceWidth());
    }
}
```

Comment: You look at the baseline. Have you also inspected the ascentline and the descentline? Or are they too unspecific?

Comment: i was looking for the text height that they had been entered with, like font.
thanks for your comments

Comment: Does the `LocationTextSizeExtractionStrategy` from [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39466192/1729265) help? (You might have to use the `RenderText` variant from the section *"Considering transformations"* to get proper results.)

Comment: Thanks for your help, i just used the ascentline and descentline